# Distribution of the k-core of a random graph

Tags: random-graphs

A *k*-core of a graph is the maximal subgraph with minimal degree *k*. For example, the 2-core would emerge by subsequently deleting degree-1 vertices of a graph.

I've seen a lot of work on existence of nontrivial *k*-cores of a random graph, and some on the number of vertices/edges in the *k*-core of a random graph. I would like to know if, for specific graph models, there are known theorems describing the distribution of the *k*-core, e.g. when the original graph is

Erdös Renyi *or*
Configuration model/given degree sequence

will the resulting 2-core be distributed as ER/configuration?

A quick comment on previous works: Janson/Luczak published "Asymptotic normality of the k-Core in random graphs" as well as "A simple solution to the k-core problem". Cooper/Frieze/Lubetzky in their paper "Cover time of a random graph with a degree sequence II: Allowing vertices of degree two" calculated the distribution of the kernel in a configuration model with minimum degree 2, but I don't think their method works for the 2-core.